# UITableViewCell with UIScrollView preventing cell touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a UITableViewCell class where I create a cell that constains a UIScrollView as its contentView.

The UIScrollView works fine and has a horizontal scrolling capability which works... however this prevents the touch method of the UITableViewCell class from working.

this is how I am adding the UIScrollView to the UITableViewCell

```
- (void)drawCell
{
    nameString = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    nameString.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    nameString.frame = CGRectMake(15.0, 0.5, 70.0, 40.0);
    nameString.text = [itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];

    addressString = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    addressString.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    addressString.frame = CGRectMake(105.0, 0.5, 95.0, 40.0);
    addressString.text = [itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"Address"];

    rd4String = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    rd4String.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    rd4String.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 10.5, rd4String.frame.size.width, 50.0);
    rd4String.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID %@: %@",[itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"name"] ,[itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"address"]];
    [rd4String sizeToFit];

    scrollCell = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    scrollCell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ScreenWidth, 45.0);
    [scrollCell setContentSize:(CGSizeMake((220.0 + rd4String.frame.size.width)+15, 45.0))];

    [scrollCell addSubview:nameString];
    [scrollCell addSubview:addressString];
    [scrollCell addSubview:rd4String];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:scrollCell];

}
```

I call this class from my UITableViewCell and everything displays properly and I can scroll the UITableViewcell I just cannot select the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Though overall detailed description of the problem is lacking, you could probably check whether you are correctly using `UITableViewDelegate` and have the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method implemented.

Also if you want to have a swipe action implemented in table cells, you could refer to one of these implementations:

- https://github.com/Dromaguirre/PDGestureTableView
- https://github.com/JLZ/JZSwipeCell